# how does authentication data interact with general data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

for example, when I make a new user with email and password sign up, I don't see that anywhere in my data ... this is a problem because i'd like to retrieve the email address input during registration by each user without storing it redundantly.

For example, I see nothing at: https://MYURLHERE.firebaseio.com/users/

or https://inferr.firebaseio.com/users/simplelogin%3A26

but that the url produced by:

alert(ref.child('users').child(user.uid));

Comment: If you are having a problem with your code, please provide what is known as an mcve: a minimal, complete, verifiable example. You'll find that you get more/better answers that way. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But in general: Firebase authentication does **not** add users to your Firebase data. You can do that yourself when the user (first) logs in. See this section on storing user data in the documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Comment: OK, perfect. In that case I'll vote to close your question, since you were helped by the Firebase documentation. If you get stuck, open a new question; preferably with an mcve if it relates to code.